# How to have custom color for tabbars and navbars?

Tags: iphone

How to set custom color for the tabbars and navbars like in this app? http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifood-assistant-by-kraft/id296246161?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the tintColor property on the navigation controllers like so:

```
myControllerController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

The tab bar they have used in the application you're linking to is a custom one. Notice how the tabs have different widths (when selected, the Shopping List tab is wider than Home for example). To my knowledge, you cannot change the colour of the UIKit tab bar.

The navigation bar is definitely also a custom one. The back buttons and the email button does not look the same shape as the UIKit ones.

Use the code above to change the colour of your navigation bar.